# How much money is spent on students' above their tuition fees in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, tuition

It is well known at the university which I went to (Cambridge), that way more money is spent on each student than the home-tier tutition fee (it is partly payed for by the exorbitant cost of international fees, and the student loans of home students are payed by the taxpayer).

UK-wide, how much money is spent on average on university students?

This question was inspired by some of the answers to this question: [Why are online lecture notes usually not accessible to non-students?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/176706/why-are-online-lecture-notes-usually-not-accessible-to-non-students)

Comment: "the student loans of home students are paid by the taxpayer" - this is not universally true at all - people pay off their loans. I paid mine off. Even when they don't fully pay them off, I would bet a reasonable portion pay off the principal. Sure, it depends on a variety of financial factors as to whether it's *worth* paying off, but the number of students for which it's beneficial to pay the loan off is non-zero.

Comment: At the time of studying, I think this is true for the overwhelming majority of students. Yes, you might pay it off later, but when you are at uni, you are essentially always paid for by the taxpayer.

Comment: @AdamWilliams I don't think this is true, especially since the rise in tuition fees. The monthly interest on my loan is practically the same as the minimum repayment for my income, so if I remain on roughly the same salary for the next few years I will never pay it off. I believe there is even talk of scrapping the system because it's clear that repayments are only going to continue falling.

Comment: @AdamWilliams and zabop: the point of disagreement between you is not actually a matter of opinion, it's a [technical question which ONS believes it has resolved in its latest accounting standards](https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/governmentpublicsectorandtaxes/publicsectorfinance/methodologies/studentloansinthepublicsectorfinancesamethodologicalguide).

Comment: I don't think Cambridge is a good comparitor. Its long been the case that educations at Cambridge (and Oxford) is considerably more expensive to provide than that at any other university, due the large amounts of teaching delivered through small group superivisions/tutorials. When I went (20 years ago), this was recognised via the seperate "college-fee" that the college recieves  per student (from the student's home local education authority I believe) on top of the standard tuition fee that the university receives, I don't know if this still applies, but it was unique to cambridge/oxford.

Comment: Also, tax payers don't pay, because the government doesn't provide the loans out of taxation, but in turn borrows the money it then lends on to students. It is more correct to say that it increases goverment borrowing, than to say that tax payers pay the costs. The arguement has been about how to account for that borrowing. Until the ONS's ruling, borrowing for student loans didn't count towards the Public Sector Net Borrowing, because the borrowing was offset against the asset value of "owning" the loan, now it does, but still only partially.

Comment: Thank you for these clarifications!

Comment: @IanSudbery The college fee still exists, but it comes out of the overall tuition fee: the student pays the University £9250, and the University passes about half of that on to the student's college.

Comment: BTW, for the University of Cambridge, the quotient of teaching income (of the University and the Colleges put together) by teaching costs (of the University and the Colleges put together)  for home/EU students on the relevant courses is 0.578.  Looking at that alongside the sector average of 0.958 given in my answer below, you're right about "not a good comparator".

Comment: @DanielHatton Interesting. Back when I was a student Oxbridge got considerably more income per student than other universities. Seems that is no longer the case. I wonder how they make up the difference? I doubt its from research grants, because these are paid to departments, but teaching is done through colleges.

Comment: @IanSudbery 'I wonder how they make up the difference?'  Endowment income, adjusted (at least at Cambridge) by a system of redistributive taxation, organised by the University, which takes some revenue from colleges with big endowments and gives it to colleges with small endowments.

Answer (score 4):

A partial answer can be found in table 2 of the [2019-2020 TRAC data](https://www.officeforstudents.org.uk/media/a6bda143-8b67-4225-966a-82f6b1488c50/2019-20-trac-peer-group-publication-annex.xlsx): cell C64 of the spreadsheet reveals that, across all UK institutions, the average quotient of teaching income by teaching costs for home/EU students on the relevant courses was 0.958.  However, that's an incomplete answer for two reasons: firstly, the "teaching income" in the numerator appears to include OfS recurrent funding for high-cost subjects and access, not just students' fees; secondly, it's not clear how data from Scotland (which has a completely different funding model) are being aggregated with data from the rest of the UK.

Comment: However one can see the breakdown between fees and grants in the finanical accounts of indevidual universities. Take for example this average Russel group research and teaching univeristy: https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/finance/annual-report-financial-statements. There was £354m in income from tuition fees and teaching contracts in 2019/2020, compared with a £24m grant from the Office for Students. There is also a £47m recurrent grant from UKRI, whcih is osensibly for reasearch, and the amount is set based on research output, but which pays salary for some people that spend some time teaching.

Comment: @IanSudbery One can also find, on the OfS website, the total amount of money OfS spends on the recurrent grants, and work out that the average quotient of recurrent teaching grant income by tuition fee income is 0.077.